# What triggers the C# FormClosed event?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, formclosing

I have an application that connects to an API. The API needs a logout function to be called when work is finished so that its system works properly. I have a function that connects to this API, does some work, and then logs out and it works correctly. The problem is when the program crashes, or I need to close it during work. 
I have added a call to the logout function in the FormClosing event in my MDI parent form. Will this work for all cases of closing the program?

To be more specific - I know, that clicking on the red X button will trigger this event. But will closing the program from the Windows' Task Manager also trigger it? And will stopping the program from Visual Studio (during development, when it was also run from Visual Studio) also trigger it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: or handle it in the form dispose

Comment: See [CloseReason](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.closereason?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: @LaurentLequenne the link does not state if this event is triggered, but how to make the function. I have the function, but I don't know if it will be always executed, no matter how the program is closed.

Comment: Dispose of an object should always be called what ever happen ... as long it's not a powercut :-)

Comment: But when the program crashes... Is this a feature  ? :)

Comment: What if the user turns off the power? you will not be logged out the same way ... what keeps you logged in? a token? store it and at the next startup check if there is still a token logged in and log out ... there will always be the possibility of logout not being done ... First of all, check the cause of the crashes. "is this a freature?" it was great

Comment: @RovannLinhalis I just came up with the same solution a minute ago. Yes, there is a session token, and I can save it during login, and log out when the application starts next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It is triggered when the user closes the program.
- It is triggered when task manager closes the program, but only some fragment of the code in FormClosing will execute, rest will be also killed
- It is not triggered when Visual Studio stops the program.
- It is not triggered when the power to a computer is cut off.

Comment: Take a look at [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.closereason?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8). It explains all the close reasons.

Comment: it was already mentioned by @preciousbetine as a comment to the question

Comment: And since it seems you have already ignored it, while I upvoted the comment, I preferred to put the comment under the answer as well. IMO, a good answer should mention the linked documentation about the close reasons.

Comment: @RezaAghaei but this documentation doesn't answer my questions.

Comment: For example: *The form is closing either programmatically or through a user action in the user interface (for example, by clicking the Close button on the form window, selecting Close from the window's control menu, or pressing ALT+F4).* → Result: X button, System Menu, Alt+F4, and by mentioning prigrammatically: it means calling Close method, setting DialogResult, ...) Or as another example: *The operating system is closing all applications before shutting down.* → Result: A proper windows shutdown.

Comment: The task manager behavior also depends to the option which you select in task manager. For example, when you select *End Task* or *End Process Tree* in details tab of task manager, it doesn't trigger the event. Or in the *Processes* tab, when you expand the application node and right click on the child node and select *End task*, it doesn't end immediately, it gives you enough time and the opportunity to cancel the event in `FormClosing` event. But if you right click on the parent node, while the event triggers, but you have a very short time to do something, but you cannot stop it.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Why don't you just write an answer?